# Import Excel Data to SQL Server 2008 Using Visual Studio 2008 C#/ASP .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, import

I'd like to know how to Import excel file to SQL Server 2008. For Example I have a textbox, browse button, and import button. I will click browse and will browse for the excel file then click import to INSERT INTO the specific table in the database all the data in the excel file (not create new table). Is there anyone who knows the codes for this? and where to put them? thank you very much. :)

Comment: That's quite a task and there are multiple ways to do it. As with every programming problem, I suggest breaking it down to smaller steps and researching how to solve each one. Steps like "How to read a file", "How to create classes/objects in C#", "how to parse strings", "excel reader libraries", "How to connect to a database" and so on...

Comment: I've been searching for hours and I cant understand most of the things i read. They just gave me this work yesterday and due later and I have no idea about this. This is the only way I can think of, asking here. I'm sorry for my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: `I cant understand most of the things I read`. Coding isn't something you pick up and understand in a day, it takes years. Please read a book to learn how to understand it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this one but I think it will have two major steps.

1. You have to create a function that can open and read the content of the excel file
   Referece: [How to open an Excel file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)
2. Read the content of excel file and import to database tables
   Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14528/Generate-SQL-INSERT-commands-programmatically
   For creating new table:
   [create sql table programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033758/create-sql-table-programmatically)

Hope that could give ideas.

Comment: im reading it right now thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

//Code ....

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration


    'Declare Variables - Edit these based on your particular situation
    Dim sSQLTable As String = "TempTableForExcelImport"
    Dim sExcelFileName As String = "myExcelFile.xls"
    Dim sWorkbook As String = "[WorkbookName$]"



    'Create our connection strings
    Dim sExcelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(sExcelFileName) & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Dim sSqlConnectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString


'Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
Dim sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sSQLTable
Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString)
Dim SqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn)
SqlConn.Open()
SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
SqlConn.Close()

'Series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our SQL table
Dim OleDbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString)
Dim OleDbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM " & sWorkbook), OleDbConn)
OleDbConn.Open()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString)
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
OleDbConn.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. When a question is tagged in a certain language, it's generally better to post code in that language.