# Create Table query with SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Which is the best way to execute a query in C# + SQL Server CE? I need to create a table, but  after 3 days of unsuccessful attempts, I realize that I really can't do it for myself... So I'm here asking for help.

I've tried these topics:

- [create sql table programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033758/create-sql-table-programmatically)
- [Data Adapter Vs Sql Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569012/data-adapter-vs-sql-command?rq=1)

But all ways I tried show me an exception... I'm confused, where is my mistake?

My current code:

```
public void Connect()
{
    try 
    {
        string FileName = "DataBase";

        using (SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\" + FileName + ".sdf;Password=Z123")) 
        {
           string query = "create table EXP(ID int, source int)";
           int i;

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
           cmd.con.open();
           i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
    catch (SqlCeException ae)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `FileName`? If you get it from `System.Io.File` it's already including the ".sdf". Also, whenever you have a question about an exception, **show us the exception**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server **CE** then you need to use a `SqlCeCommand` (not a `SqlCommand` - that's for the full-blown SQL Server).

So change your code to:

```
using (SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\" + FileName + ".sdf;Password=Z123")) 
{
    string query = "create table EXP(ID int, source int)";

    // use SqlCeCommand here!! Also: use the "myConnection" SqlCeConnection you're 
    // opening at the top - don't use something else.....
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, myConnection);

    myConnection.open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```